# Running as.Node from data.tree package in R

Tags: r, tree, nodes

I'm trying to use the as.Node function from the data.tree library in R to visualize a set of media server log data as a tree. I've subset the original data frame by month and year, so that I can run one month's worth of data at a time. My function code for turning the data into a tree, and then printing it out as a .csv, is as follows:

```
treetrimmer2 <- function(x, y) {
  urimodel <- as.Node(x)
  uridf <- ToDataFrameTree(urimodel, "level", "count")
  uridf <- filter(uridf, level <= y, count != 0)
  filename <- paste(x$year[1], x$month[1], ".csv", sep="")
  write.csv(uridf, file = filename, fileEncoding = "CP1252")
}
```

Some months finish without any issue. Other months, however, give me the following error (and traceback):

```
Error in (function ()  : unused argument (quote(<environment>)) 

7 (function () 
{
    c(self$parent$path, self$name)
})(quote(<environment>)) 
6 self$AddChildNode(child) 
5 mynode$AddChild(path) 
4 FromDataFrameTable(x, pathName, pathDelimiter, colLevels, na.rm) 
3 as.Node.data.frame(x) 
2 as.Node(x) at media_visualizer.R#63
1 treetrimmer2(uricut$`2015.06`, 5)
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on what 'unused argument (quote())' means? I've tried googling it, and found that in some cases, it means that a function or term has already been defined in another context. But I'm still too novice to understand what that means here.

I'm running rStudio 0.99.896 and R 3.2.4 on Mac OS 10.11.5. I would share my data set, except that it is pretty massive, and I'm not sure which lines are causing the problem...

Comment: That does look like a bug. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it. So can you please send me the data set? (to the email provided as the data.tree maintainer: see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/ ). Also: are you using data.tree 0.3.5 (i.e. currently the latest from CRAN)?

Comment: I'm happy to share my dataset. Through a gradual process of splitting it in two and running both halves, I've been able to narrow the problem down to a set of 20,000 lines, which will fit in an email. And I am using data.tree 0.3.5.

Comment: This is a really intriguing bug. See https://github.com/gluc/data.tree/issues/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim credit for this; Christoph Glur (see the comments on the main post) figured it out. But it might be useful for others to share the cause, and my solution:

The problem is that a few of the log files contain one of the data.tree package's reserved words, in this case, "path". The format of the lines was "/something/something/path/something/something.jpg", so that data.tree read "path" as an independent word. There were other instances of "path" as part of a larger word, e.g., "pathString" or "pathTo", that didn't cause the bug.

Once he'd figured it out, my solution was to run the following command on all of the log files in Terminal:

```
sed -i '' 's/\/path\//\/spath\//' *.log
```

I'm still a novice, but as I understand it, what that means is "find and replace, in place, instances of "/path/" with "/spath/" in all of the .log files." I don't actually care about that one word, path vs. spath (which is gibberish), so changing it didn't matter. And now the as.Node() function runs properly on the data set.

Thank you, Christoph!